# The BEST way to do not share connection string to hackers

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string, desktop-application, password-protection

I am currently working on a WinForms .NET application that will be made available to end users. The question is: how (BEST) to hide the Connection string, so that the hackers, after decompiling the program, do not have access to my database?

I thought to create a user who will only use the procedures on the base.

I searched the entire forum and found some comments about resource, config.app, etc.

@PanagiotisKanavos Exacly , targetting to Mysql database

But it does not protect 100%.

Is there any way in 2019 that will protect you from giving away the login and password used in the application?

```
Connection  currently is in my c# code and looks like :
string connectionstring = "Server = servername;Port=1111;Database=databasename;Uid=login;Pwd=password;Convert Zero Datetime=True";
```

Comment: Yes, it's the same way that has been in place for many years: don't give code containing secret credentials to end users. End of story. If your client app needs to talk to your database, it should do so through an API that you control.

Comment: If you are able to use windows credentials then you do not need to store a user id and password. Connection string would look something like this: Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

Comment: `Is there any way in 2019` the same ways that worked perfectly well all those years. *DON'T* hide the connection string. *DON'T* use a username/password, use Windows authentication. *Encrypt* specific sections, the way ASP.NET applications do since 2002. `Uid` isn't used in SQL Server though so I suspect you're targeting a MySQL database? Please *be specific*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exacly , targetting Mysql database

Comment: @adam MySQL can [use Windows authentication too](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-pluggable-authentication.html). That *does* protect 100% against credential leaks. You haven't explained *what* you want to protect against though? Why not create a minimal-priviledge account for each user and have them *enter* the credentials when they start the application?

Comment: First and most important thing considering security is: "there **is** no such thing as 100% security". So which 0.1% are you talking about? You have to **know** what you want to avoid.

Comment: @adam apart from that, Windows and .NET have mechanisms of protecting data at the machine and user level. Instead of storing the credentials in the connection string, use eg [ProtectData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.protect?view=netframework-4.7.2) to encrypt and protect the credentials after the first succesful login. You could even use hardware encryption through the same API using the appropriate drivers.

Comment: @adam what HimBromBeere said, 100 times over. *What* do you want to protect against? Different techniques protect against different threats. How much does failure cost too? You could buy a KMS for example, but that could cost more than the license for SQL Server. Having users login each time is a lot cheaper

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want to protect my user login and password to my database . I can create a user and give him only grants to execute stored procedure  but this don't change fact someone can decomplie code and get password and login.

Comment: @adam *don't* store that password and login then. Let the user type them in when they start the application. Or configure Windows Authentication in MySQL and forget about passwords completely. As for that `MySQL Enterprise Edition for Windows supports an authentication`, you can download the source for Enterprise Edition and compile it yourself.

Comment: As @Marvin and I said, you should create a web API to interact with your database. You can then have a login mechanism which authenticates the client with the API and you then have API methods which get data / effect changes on your database.

Comment: But when the user type then  MY account must get values from database.  So it's important that only my account can get this information from database

Answer (score 3):

**There is no way of keeping your connection string safe if you intent the client machine to have access to it**

No matter how you provide the connection string to the client, anyone with malicious intent can access the memory of the application and retrieve the connection string at run time.

Comment: The connection string doesn't *need* to be kept safe. Only the credentials. And yes, there are ways to protect the entire connection string.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Even still, if the credentials are loaded into the application at any point in time, anyone with malicious intent can intercept or read it from the application's memory.

Comment: Not really. You don't need to use any credentials when using eg Windows Authentication. If that "someone" has such access to your machine that he/she can install a *debugger*, he/she already has access to everything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If the user was to be allowed access with Windows auth (though out of scope since this question concerns MySQL), the user would have access to the database anyways and OP would probably not be worried about sharing the connection string (except if he wishes to be able to revoke access for single users which also isn't really possible with a single connection string).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use an API to interact with the data from the database. Using a token which is handed to the user using the program.

Comment: That is what the user's application is doing already. Adding an "API" won't change the fact that you *still* need to add that username/password somewhere. Adding *more* software will only create *more* ways the credentials can leak

Comment: @Panagiotis I think you have the wrong end of the stick with this one. Imagine OP has created Facebook but in a WinForms app. Your solution is to have the user enter the Facebook database credentials when they open the app.

Comment: @John or I may have used all those techniques for years

Comment: @Panagiotis Are you suggesting then that each customer/end-user has an account on the database server itself, and roles are created for those users?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way in 2019 that will protect you from giving away the
>   login and password used in the application?

Sure there is. Instead of having that connection string in your supplication code, have it in a config file like `web.config` or `App.config`. Then you can use *Azure Key Vault* or *Environment Variable* to completely have that connection string in key vault and have only the azure key vault reference url in your config file.

Read more about Key Vault https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis

Per one of the comment, if your end goal is to distribute the `exe`; then as well you should have the connection string in config file and should consider encrypting and storing the encrypted one in your config file. Read more on *Protected Configuration* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis

Comment: @John doesn't matter. Key vault works in either case

Comment: I mean, I think it's an application that OP is distributing to end users, that has access to some kind of shared database. P.S. I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: @John that's how connection strings get protected since 2002. *Don't* hide them, use Windows authentication, or *encrypt* specific sections of the config file. Those things are available since 2002. Credential storage in an Azure or Amazon key vault is the only new thing

Comment: @Panagiotis But what prevents someone who receives or purchases the client application from simply reverse engineering it, accessing KeyVault, and then extracting the connection string from there?

Comment: @John that someone is the owner of the *database* too. The guy that will have to pay the GDPR fine if anything leaks. If you worry about employees reading the connection string, why should they be able to do anything more with them than they can do with the application? In other words, don't use `sa` or `sys` as the application's user, use a personalized minimum priviledge account

Comment: @John those things can never be protected and that's why there is security audits and other stuff right.

Comment: @Rahul That's my point. It's exactly why the correct solution for OP is to not give the client application direct access to the database, but instead allow the client application to consume it through an API. Requiring the application to go to KeyVault to get the key is just adding more steps. Remember that OP's current plan involves hard-coding the connection string into the application, which suggests one database for many customers.

Answer (score 1):

There are out of the box methods to encrypt your configuration. ASP.NET 2.0 introduced a new feature, called protected configuration, that enables you to encrypt sensitive information in a configuration file. Although primarily designed for ASP.NET, protected configuration can also be used to encrypt configuration file sections in Windows applications. For a detailed description of the protected configuration capabilities read these two articles from msdn:

[Protecting connection information in general](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/protecting-connection-information)

[Encrypting connectionstrings and configuration sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#encrypting-configuration-file-sections-using-protected-configuration)

Comment: If it's encrypted it can be decrypted, and the decryption key will be available to the application, thus also to the end user.

Comment: @ikkentim please *read* those links. Yes, it can be decrypted *but only on the server itself*. That's why this kind of encryption is used in web applications. The key used is the machine's own key, the same one used to protect your credit card information. In general, it's advised to use *domain accounts* instead of local accounts and user/password combinations in web applications.

Comment: @Panagiotis which server? We're talking about a WinForms client application here. From reading the question, OP has no server other than their database server.

Comment: @John *database server*. And config encryption works for *any* config file, not just those named `web.config`. It works on any machine, not just those running a Server SKU

Comment: @Panagiotis I'm not misunderstanding config encryption, but that doesn't seem to be what OP's issue is with. OP's issue seems to be that end-users need credentials for the database.